# How to change colors options in Highcharts programmatically?

Tags: highcharts

In highcharts initialization I've set array of only one color. I would like to change this with another array on charts's hover event. In other words chart is default monochromatic and after hover it becomes colorful.

```
config = {
    colors: ["#C0C0C0"]
};

chart = $('#chart').highcharts(config).highcharts()

$('#chart').hover(function(){
    chart.options.colors = ["#E84C3D", "#C1392B", '#D25400', "#E67F22", "#F39C11"]
}, function(){
    chart.options.colors = ["#C0C0C0"]
});
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. How should I do it?

Comment: You would have to update each elements' color options then redraw the chart. Once the chart has been drawn the colors options is not read again until redraw. Not really sure what a monochrome chart would be useful for but to each their own.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the plotOptions events:

`plotOptions: {
        column:{colorByPoint:true},
        series: {
            animation:false,
            events: {
                mouseOver: function(e) {
                    //console.log( chart.options);
                      var options = chart.options;
                      if(options.colors[0]!='#E84C3D')
                      {

                          options.colors=['#E84C3D','#C1392B','#D25400','#E67F22','#F39C11'];
                          chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                      }
                },
                mouseOut: function(e) {
                    var options = chart.options;
                      if(options.colors[0]!='#C0C0C0')
                      {

                          options.colors=['#C0C0C0'];
                          chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                      }
                }
            }
        }
    }`

demo http://jsfiddle.net/eNMvw/134/

Comment: It's returning error `TypeError: b is undefined` and working at jsfiddle at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Instad of creating chart multiple time, better is using [series.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update) and apply colors per bars.